# ValueError: time data 04-Jan-10 doesn't match format specified

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to convert

> 05-oct-2020 to 2020-10-05

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I'm getting the `ValueError: time data 04-Jan-10 doesn't match format specified`

Comment: Use the correct [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for documentation I will go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%b-%d')
```

or

Month to month number:

```
from time import strptime

month = df.Date[3:3]
monthNumber = strptime(month,'%b').tm_mon
```

I don't know the indexes ( the `[3:3]` part ) precisely but I think it is good.

Tweak that part if necessary.

Comment: Why not simply use `%b` as part of the format string that parses the date?

Comment: Well that's the correct way to do it. Slicing out the month name part and converting it to a number is an unnecessarily convoluted way.

Comment: @Komali Glad to help!